# Обработка ошибки и передача через поток char

Tags: c++, исключения, c++11, обработка-ошибок

Функция конвертирует **std::string в тип T**. Передача "-1" в числовые типы считается ошибкой. Передача "Abc" в char тоже.

```
template<class T>
T from_string(std::string const& s)
{
    try
    {
        T obj;
        if (! (std::istringstream(s) >> std::noskipws >> obj) ) throw new bad_from_string(s);
        return obj;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {}
}
```

Обработчик ошибок:

```
class bad_from_string : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    bad_from_string(const char* msg) : std::runtime_error(msg) {}
    bad_from_string(std::string const& msg) : std::runtime_error(msg.c_str()) {}

    const char* msg;
};
```

**Вопрос**: как отловить передачу в char более, чем одного символа и передачу в численные типы числа со знаком "-"?

В отмеченных случаях char должен выдавать ошибку
[image: В отмеченных случаях char должен выдавать ошибку]

Comment: Проверить длину строки. В случае ASCII символов она должна быть = 1. Знак "-" - проверка первого символа. В чём проблема?

Comment: @cppquestions Длину строки проверять ещё до записи в obj? Со знаком минус так же?

Comment: Да, почему бы и нет

Comment: я вам написал пример в прошлом вопросе. То что  вы тут написали содержит грубые ошибки

Comment: @ARHovsepyan спасибо, Ваш ответ прочитал. В чём заключаются грубые ошибки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем  с вашего класса:

Во первых неинициализирован указатель `msg`, не говоря о том, что он тут вообше не нужен.

Во вторых, класс, хранящий указатель, должен иметь определение  деструктора, КК и ОП.

И наконец: `std::runtime_error` принимает как С_строку, так и std::string, а последный, в свою очередь может инициализироваться С_строкой, так что одного единственного конструктора достаточно.  И старайтесь придать разные имена аргументу конструктора и члену класса, чтобы потом самы не запутались. Нормально `bad_from_string`  может выглядеть:

```
struct bad_from_string : public std::runtime_error
{   
    bad_from_string(std::string const& msg) : std::runtime_error(msg) {}    
};
```

Теперь о вашей функции: она генерирует исключение и сама же ловит. Во первых смысла в этом абсолютно нет, поскольку исключения генерируются, чтобы вызывающая функция обрабатывала и получала нужный результат. Во вторых: если исключение поймано, то ваша функция не закончит свою работу, а значит не вернет ничего, но она должна возвращать обьект.

Так что уберите `try/catch` из функции и включите в программу(вызывающую функцию). А если вы хотите читать из потока так, как вам хочется, то нужно написать еще и парсер.

P.S. Чуть не забыл:  не нужно генерировать исключение, созданное в куче, поскольку в этом нет нужды, плюс иначе вам придется не забывать производить удаление в обработчике, и вы все таки пытаетесь обработать не по указателью, а по ссыльке.

Comment: `не нужно генерировать исключение, созданное в куче` - если не затруднит, можно детали?

Comment: @NewView,  просто в данном примере нет нужды. И отпадет необходимость  удалять обьект в обработчике.   Класс исключения такой простой, что даже копию можно обработать, а не ссыльку